# How to combine Apache redirects?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I've got an Apache config that features multiple rewrite rules and redirects in order to get the cutest URLs, prevent duplicates for SEO, etc. Here's a snippet as an example (it features a lot more):

```
# Redirecting non-www to www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Removing index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* / [R=301,L]

# A big bunch of these
Redirect permanent /old-article.html  http://www.example.com/new-article.html
Redirect permanent /another-old-article.html  http://www.example.com/new-article2.html
```

This works well, but it happens to generate a lot of redirects. A common case looks like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php, 301 redirect to http://www.example.com/index.php
http://www.example.com/index.php, 301 redirect to http://www.example.com
```

It sometimes reaches 4-5 redirects.

Now, I want all these rules to be chained and generate only one 301 redirect, like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php, 301 redirect to http://www.example.com
```

I know I can spend an afternoon thinking and sorting the rules to a better match, and also that I can create combined rules. But that would complicate an already long file. I want a flag, operand or whatever that will execute all the rules as if they where internal and only issue the redirect once it has crawled every rule. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if simply re-ordering this would get you what you want:

```
# A big bunch of these
Redirect permanent /old-article.html  http://www.example.com/new-article.html
Redirect permanent /another-old-article.html  http://www.example.com/new-article2.html

# Removing index.php
RewriteRule ^/index.php http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

# Redirecting non-www to www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

A direct request for an old article at the `example.com` domain:

```
http://example.com/old-article.html
```

Will result in a single redirect to:

```
http://www.example.com/new-article.html
```

A request for either `http://example.com/index.php` or `http://www.example.com/index.php` will result in a single redirect to:

```
http://www.example.com/
```

A request that doesn't match anything else will result in a single redirect from:

```
http://example.com/foo
```

To:

```
http://www.example.com/foo
```

This seems to cover all the bases.  Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `[L]` flag from your `RewriteRule`s, and they will be combined automatically.