# How to combine different apache redirects?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to combine different apache redirects. I thought just getting rid of any `L`ast flag would do the trick but it didn't (see [How to combine Apache redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13735230/1981832)). It makes the following two landing page redirects

`example.org` -> `www.example.org` -> `www.example.org/products/`

But I'd rather have

`example.org` -> `www.example.org/products/`

to avoid delays.

Here is the `.htaccess` file:

```
# FORCE WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301]

# REDIRECT FROM ROOT TO PRODUCTS(.PHP)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^$ /products/ [R]
RewriteRule ^products/$ /products/products.php

# ADD TRAILING SLASH
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^./]+)$ http://www.example.org/$1/ [R=301]

# INTERNAL REWRITE OF "products/myname/myversion/" to "products/products.php?name=myname&version=myversion"
RewriteRule ^products/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9-]+)/$ products/products.php?name=$1&version=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^products/([a-z0-9-]+)/$ products/products.php?name=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this currently I did not tried it,

```
#FORCE WWW with products 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^products
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/products/$1 [R=301]
```

And remove these lines

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^$ /products/ [R]
```

Comment: Thanks. But it does not work. I think your code will redirect to the `products` folder *only if* there is no leading `www`.

Comment: Thanks again. Now since `example.com/products` does not fulfill the second condition it would not redirect to `www.example.com/products`  or am I missing something? But the general idea is to have only one `R` or `R=301` flag per redirect, right? So every `R(=301)` leads to a redirect independent of whether some additional redirect is added later on?

Comment: As per your example above you mention no leading www now you are asking that it will not work for leading www?

Comment: I don't follow. I need to add (1) `www` if there is none and (2) `/products` if there is none. In the first solution you posted, `www.example.org` did not redirect to `www.example.org/products` which violates (2). In the current solution `example.org/products` will not redirect to `www.example.org/product` which violates (1). Or am I confused?